# Oracle doesn't release or kill inactive process and/or session from my ASP.NET Application pool

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection-pooling, odp.net, application-pool

We Just ran into a problem with our website.  We are running a Oracle 12c database and using IIS 8 on a Windows 12 Azure server.  ODP.NET is the provider we use.  The website is build in C# and run as a 64bit web application.

For Whatever reason,  Oracle  doesn't release our connections, and after a while we got an Oracle Error :

```
ORA-12520: TNS:listener could not find available handler for requested type of server
```

We  reviewed all of our connections string,  adding :

```
Min Pool Size=10;Max Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=120;Connection Timeout=60;Incr Pool Size=5; Decr Pool Size=2
```

We more than double the MAX Process and Sessions that was defined in the Oracle configuration.

It's help but only in delaying the problem.

For now what we have done is a batch file which run every 10 minutes and kills all inactive sessions that are still there after 30 minutes  (ALTER SESSION KILL....IMMEDIATE).

That's where we are,  we have enable the ODP.NET trace and waiting to look at it tomorrow, but by this time, what can cause this problem?

Comment: Which .net ADO Oracle client are you using? What does the code look like that makes connections? Poorly written code that does not use `using` blocks or `finally` blocks to close each connection after it is used can be a culprit. Without more information there is probably not much anyone can do for you.

Comment: Sorry just look at my answer.  I was documenting for other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally what I found in the ODP.NET Trace was

```
TID: dac  (ERROR) Oracle error code=28002; Oracle msg=ORA-28002: the password will expire within 6 days
```

Seems that this Error doesn't stop the access to the DB but hang the session in the pool.

After we fixed that, all was back to normal.